# Add users' linked account ids to the data dump

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, users, data-dump, linked-accounts

Adding this would seem like a low effort/high reward type of thing. It would certainly open up a lot of possibilities in seeing how the Trilogy is used as a whole, instead of analyzing individual sites in a vacuum.

To make it easy to integrate into the [current structure](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/anatomy-of-a-data-dump), this data could be exported in a new "table" with 4 columns (one for each Trilogy site user id; NULLable to account for no linkage), with one row per user.

Obviously, this would be a Trilogy-specific feature, so in terms of file structure, the new data should go in a separate folder from the 4 dump folders.

Since everyone's linked accounts are shown publicly on the user page, I don't think there are any privacy concerns that need to be dealt with here.

Comment: that sounds similar to the way I suggested the data be included http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23615/include-all-sites-in-future-data-dumps

Comment: @Kyle: Yes, you're right. Sorry, I didn't see that post. Hmmm.. what should I do with this question?

Comment: note you can get a pretty accurate estimate using the EmailHash

Comment: This question is OK - it's an issue that was never addressed. I was mainly trying to populate the "Linked" section.

Answer (score 1):

The [`users`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/472607/information-schema-for-a-table?table=users) file has as documented since [February 2014](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/2678/29) an AccountId attribute. This enables to link users between several sites. Notice that the attribute `emailhash`, as mentioned in the comments, is now always null in SEDE and for that reason non-existent in the users.xml in the data-dump.

I used AccountId in some questions I answered, for example:

- [Determining how much reputation was received from which post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263346/determining-how-much-reputation-was-received-from-which-post/284148#284148)
- [Is there any way to find which SE site is a gateway drug?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281155/is-there-any-way-to-find-which-se-site-is-a-gateway-drug/284133#284133)
- [Is there a way to find out how many edits I've made, network-wide?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291912/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-how-many-edits-ive-made-network-wide/297933#297933)