# Is there a way to find out how many edits I've made, network-wide?

Tags: support, edits, data-explorer

I'm a prolific editor. I've made edits on a whole bunch of different sites. I'd like to know exactly how many edits I've made, *network-wide*. Is there a way to find out, perhaps with SEDE?

Comment: There is a way to do it. I don't have time to write the SQL now, but it's possible, if convoluted, to [query across all sites on Stack Exchange in SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/305411/is-there-a-way-to-get-people-reached-sum-across-entire-network-for-a-user).

Comment: One could also theoretically code up something that uses the API, first using `/users/{id}/associated` to get a list of all accounts, then for each using `/users/{id}/timeline` and counting the revision items. Unfortunately the activity -> revisions page on the network profile limits the displayed items so that's not a route you can take.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) for that if you don't mind the data can be up to 7 days behind.

For your purpose I've create [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/690463/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-how-many-edits-ive-made-network-wide?accountid=5129611) that visits each database and then finds the rows in the posthistory table for events of type 4, 5 and 6 (title, body and tag edits). The aggregate of the per database result is stored and then in the end queried to form the final result. I didn't bother to filter out edits on your own posts but feel free to make the adjustments needed for a [single site](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/690447) before you edit the change in your own fork.

The query needs your accountid, which you can find in the url of [your network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/5129611/mithrandir).

Notice the join on the posthistory table twice. That is done so the query plan includes the only non-clustered index on the posthistory table. Without using that index, SQL Server does an index scan and PostHistory has too many rows to complete all that scanning in under 2 minutes. Hence the trickery.

```sql
declare @accountid as int = ##accountid?5129611##

-- result table, don't rename and keep the site column
create table #results ( site nvarchar(250)
                       , title int
                       , body int
                       , tag int
                       , revs int);

declare @sql nvarchar(max) = ''   -- holds build up sql string

-- build one biq union sql, for each db
select @sql = @sql 
+ iif( len(@sql) > 1 
     , 'union'
     , 'insert into #results'
) +
-- here goes the per site query, fully qualify the database objects
N'
select ''' + name + '''
     , sum([4]) as [title]
     , sum([5]) as [body]
     , sum([6]) as [tag]
     , count(*) as [revtot]
from 
(
select revisionguid 
     , [4] 
     , [5]
     , [6]
 from
(select ph2.revisionguid 
      , ph2.posthistorytypeid
from ' + quotename(name) + '.dbo.posthistory ph
inner join ' + quotename(name) + '.dbo.users u 
   on u.id =  ph.userid 
   and u.accountid = ' + cast(@accountid as nvarchar) +' 
inner join ' + quotename(name) + '.dbo.posthistory ph2 
   on ph.id = ph2.id
where ph.posthistorytypeid between 4 and 6 )  as data
pivot
(
   count(posthistorytypeid)
   for posthistorytypeid in ([4] , [5], [6]) 
) as pvt
) alldata
'
from sys.databases
where database_id > 5

-- execute it
exec (@sql)

-- show results

select 'total' as site
     , sum(title) as title
     , sum(body) as body
     , sum(tag) as tag
     , sum(revs) as [#revisions]
from #results
where revs > 0
union all
select *
from #results
where revs > 0

drop table #results
```

When run today this is what the result will look like:

[image: all edits networkwide]

Keep in mind SEDE is only updated once a week, on Sunday.
Use the neat [SEDE Tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) written by the awesome [Monica Cellio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/162102/monica-cellio).
Say "Hi" in [SEDE chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1223/data-explorer-sede).

Comment: 'feel free to' - heh. I can't code for my life :P Thanks; this is awesome!